# Where is $x(t)y(t)$ in the transpose rule when $A = d/dt$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

In Introduction to Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang changes a difference matrix to the derivative $A=d/dt$ such that the transpose rule

$$
(Ax)^T y = x^T (A^T y)
$$

becomes

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{dt}y(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)(-\frac{dy}{dt})dt
$$

This looks like integration by parts

$$
\int x'(t)y(t)dt = x(t)y(t) - \int x(t)y'(t)dt
$$

but without $x(t)y(t)$! Where does the product go?

Comment: For the integral to converge, I think the underlying assumption is that $x(t)y(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $|t| \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What is the actual vector space Strang is working with here? The inner product is the $L^2$ inner product ... on what set of functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin, vector space will be described in the next chapter but it's possible that Strang is wetting our appetite for what's to come.

Comment: Strang gives wonderful intuition, but is often sloppy with precise definitions.